# Responsive d3 choropleth showing commuter flows between counties?

Tags: d3

I would like to create a responsive choropleth using d3. When one clicks on a county, the choropleth updates to reflect commuter flows between that county and all others. Example input data looks like this:

```
"home","work","flow"
01001,01007,10
01001,01015,10
01001,01021,383
01001,01047,271
01001,01051,1624
01001,01073,71
01001,01081,50
01001,01097,80
01001,37119,10
01001,40143,10
01001,48029,45
01001,48141,10
01001,51041,35
13121,01003,35
13121,01071,15
13121,01073,69
13121,01081,4
13121,01089,70
13121,01097,55
13121,01121,10
13121,01125,15
13121,04005,10
13121,04013,65
```

In the [unemployment choropleth](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606) example where the choropleth map is static, the input data is read in like this:

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "data/us.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "data/unemployment.tsv", function(d) { rateById.set(d.id, +d.rate); })
    .await(ready);
```

Future calls on `rateById` use `get()` (e.g., `rateById.get(d.id)`). See below from the unemployment example.

```
quantize(rateById.get(d.id));
```

If I have the commuter flow two-dimensional dataset, I expect that calls on `flowByHomeByWork` would look like `flowByHomeByWork.get(currFIPS).get(d.id)`. For example,

```
quantize(flowByHomeByWork.get(currFIPS).get(d.id));
```

How do I map the data when reading it in with `queue()` to facilitate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the unemployment choropleth example, `rateById` is a `d3.map`, which as far as I know can really only store two values. You have three: the origin, the destination, and the flow amount.

I would load the data normally, like so:

```
queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "data/us.json")
  .defer(d3.tsv, "data/commute.tsv")
  .await(ready);
```

and then use a method like lo-dash's [_.filter](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) on a click to return the values you want:

```
var flowsToMap = _.filter(commute, function(d) { return d.home === clickedFips; })
```

You can then grab an array of flow values in `flowsToMap` to use as the domain for the quantize scale using [_.pluck](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck) or similar.

Answer (score 1):

`queue()` is for asynchronous loading of data. So assuming all of your data is loaded, you do not need to use `queue()` again after the data is loaded, and control is handed to `ready` by `.await(ready)`.

I think what you are looking for is to assign click behavior to the map. You can do this in `ready`, by referencing an onclick function

```
map = d3.select('#map').append('svg');
map.append('g')
   .selectAll('path')
   .data(topojson.feature(map_data, map_data.objects.counties).features)
   .enter().append('path')
   .attr('d', PATH)
   .attr('class', 'states')
   // Add mouse events
   .on('click', mouseclick);

function mouseclick(d) { 
   // redraw the map with flow for this county
   county_id = d.id;
   ...
}
```

This is by no means a complete example... You need to do all the basic setup before appending data to the map (scale, projection), and there will be a lot of work to define what happens after a county is clicked

Comment: I've got that part covered through other examples, e.g., Flowing Data's Compare Worst and Best Commutes in America. The part I've been struggling with for two days is how to update the fill colors given the selected county. This adds another dimension than all the choropleth maps I've been able to find using d3.

Comment: if you can draw the map once, and you know what the values are for counties after a user selects one, abstract the map drawing into a function, and call it with new color scale after a user clicks the map. Without a more complete example to work from, it's difficult to help, there are a lot of ways this could work (or not).